# extract xpath

Tags: xpath

I want to retrieve the xpath of an attribute (example "brand" of a product from a retailer website).

One way of doing it is using addons like xpather or xpath checker to firefox, opening up the website using firefox and right clicking the desired attrbute I am interested in. This is ok. But I want to capture this information for many attributes and right clicking each and every attribute maybe time consuming. Also, the other problem I have is that attributes I maybe interested in will be there for one product. The other attributes maybe for some other product. So, I will have to go that product & then do it manually again.

Is there an automated or programatic way of retrieving the xpath of the desired attributes from a website rather than having to do this manually?

Answer (score 1):

You must notice that not all websites use valid XML that you can use xpath on...

That said, you should check out some HTML parsers that will allow you to use xpath on HTML even if it is not a valid XML.

Since you did not specify the technology you are working with - I'll suggest the .NET [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack), if you need others, search for questions dealing with this here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use for this kind of thing is to write an xpath something like this:

```
//*[text()="Brand"]/following-sibling::*
//*[text()="Color"]/following-sibling::*
//*[text()="Size"]/following-sibling::*
//*[text()="Material"]/following-sibling::*
```

It works by finding all elements (labels) with the text you want and then looking to the next sibling in the HTML. Without a specific URL to see I can't help any further.

This is a generalised version you can make more specific versions by replacing the asterisks is tag types, and you can navigate differently by replacing the axis following sibling with something else.

I use xPaths in import.io to make APIs for this kind of thing all the time, It's just a matter of finding a xPath that's generic enough to find the HTML no matter where it is on the page, but being specific enough to get the right data.